# Spring validation ConstraintViolationException cannot be caught using ControllerAdvice

Tags: spring-mvc

I am building APIs with spring rest and trying to validate the input parameters, like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/myUrl")
@RestController
@Validated
public class MyController {

  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
  @RequestMapping(value = "getSomething", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
  public myResponse getMarketResult(
  @RequestParam @NotNull @NotBlank @NotEmpty String inputParam) {
    //...my implementation
  }
}
```

The validation does work in all these scenarios (null, blanks, empty).
MissingServletRequestParameterException is thrown for null, ConstraintViolationException is thrown for blanks/empty.

Controller advice:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ControllerValidationHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

  @ExceptionHandler(NestedServletException.class)
  public ResponseEntity<Object> processValidationError(NestedServletException ex, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
    // my implementation
  }

  @ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
  public ResponseEntity<Object> processValidationError(ConstraintViolationException ex, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
    // my implementation
  }

  @Override
  protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMissingServletRequestParameter(MissingServletRequestParameterException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
    // my implementation
  }

  @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
  public ResponseEntity<Object> handleExpception(HttpServletRequest req, Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
    // my implementation
  }
```

However I observe:

1. ConstraintViolationException is thrown as the cause of org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException.
2. ControllerAdvice is unable to catch ConstraintViolationException and NestedServletException (But MissingServletRequestParameterException works), it's now returning a html (instead of json).

The 2 exceptions are not processed by 'handleException' of ResponseEntityExceptionHandler as well.

How do I solve 1 and 2? I'm using Spring version 4.3.1

Edit 1:
One more example, if I have a parameter like this:

```
@RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) @NotNull LocalDate localDate
```

Expcetion is thrown as mentioned in (1) when the request is empty (eg '/myURL/getSomething?localDate='

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having the same issue